# Why Unable to get success callback in Jquery/ajax call to RESTful services?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, rest

```
function GET() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:32253/api/UserDetail/GetRoleDetails',
            type: 'GET',
            async:true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            error: function (xhr, status)
            {
                alert(status);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success!");
            }

        });
        return false;
    }
```

I am very much new to ajax,I tried a ajax call to my services method which returns value.But the success callback function is never fired .I only get error.What might be the reason?
I tried using dataType to jsonp and other similar solutions which had been found in Stackoverflow regarding this issue.Nothing worked out.I am getting server response as 200 oK.

Comment: Try to use `complete` instead of `success`.

Comment: What is the payload for the request? Is the rest service expecting some parameters? why don't you post the code of your rest service.

Comment: it may be issue with content origin policy, add your domain in the Content-Security-Policy and try.

Comment: I am able to get the Success callback in IE but fails in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        jsonp: "onJSONPLoad",
        jsonpCallback: "newarticlescallback",
        crossDomain: "false",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log("Error In Web Service...." + request.responseText);
            return false;
        },
        success: ajax_success,
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
        }
    });
```

create  function "ajax_success" in ur page 
like below

```
function ajax_success(parsedJSON) { //you code here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be help you
try this code

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        jsonp: "onJSONPLoad",
        jsonpCallback: "newarticlescallback",
        crossDomain: "false",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log("Error In Web Service...." + request.responseText);
            return false;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            Result = data;
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried in IE i am able to get respones but fails in the case of chrome.